# Notes / iNotes Calendar Date Picker Navigation

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

In notes apps you have the ability to embed a date picker which dives you a calendar you can use to navigate a calendar view. iNotes also has this is the left hand navigation. It takes you to that date in the calendar you are viewing.

My question is, is there a technique that provides something similar for an xPages application?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the sample DB on openNTF?

Comment: I did not see anything. I added an image to help clarify what I am looking for. It isn't the Date Time Picker in the core controls. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not realy shure what exactly you are looking for but maby this helps you:
In XPages you can use several things to display a calendar or select Dates from a Calendar Widget for your input fields:

1) A simple Date Picker field from the Core Controls:

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{viewScope.date}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="date"></xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
    <xp:dateTimeHelper>
</xp:dateTimeHelper>
</xp:inputText>
```

2) Use the [dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) widget See [example page](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/2.1/docPublic/examples.htm?content=dojowidgets.htm).

3) The iNotesCalendar control from the extention library. The [TeamRoom](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/TeamRoom%20OpenNTF%208.5.2/screenshots) template includes a nice example how you can use it.

```
<xe:calendarView></xe:calendarView>
```

Comment: I have used the calendarView, but what I am looking for is using a calendar as a page navigator for changing the date and connect it to the calendarView. Think the iNotes or Notes client calendar page ui where the left panel navigation has the small calendar that changes the calendar view in the content panel.